# Time with DST for any city in JS/Java

Tags: java, javascript, clock, datetime-format, dst

I want to have a code which will work in below manner.
    display time of 8-10 cities in which the DST should be handled automatically.

```
For example : Melbourne observes DST, a API using which I can fetch the current time based on location without any hardcode done for DST calculation.
```

Currently the code which is working is based on hardcoded values.It picks the system time converts to GMT and then  add/subtract offset based on location.

Then calculate the DST based on dates and add appropriately.

But I want to use some API to remove the hardcoded values, I m trying to use the below code.

```
The below code giving time for IST/GMT, but when I put AEST/AEDT it doesnt give the correct time.


public class DateFormatter {

    public static String formatDateToString(Date date, String format,
            String timeZone) {
        // null check
        if (date == null) return null;
        // create SimpleDateFormat object with input format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        // default system timezone if passed null or empty
        if (timeZone == null || "".equalsIgnoreCase(timeZone.trim())) {
            timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID();
        }
        // set timezone to SimpleDateFormat
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
        // return Date in required format with timezone as String
        return sdf.format(date);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Test formatDateToString method
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("Default Date:"+date.toString());
        System.out.println("System Date: "+formatDateToString(date, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a", null));
        System.out.println("System Date in PST: "+formatDateToString(date, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "PST"));
        System.out.println("System Date in IST: "+formatDateToString(date, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "IST"));
        System.out.println("System Date in GMT: "+formatDateToString(date, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "GMT"));
        System.out.println("System Date in CT: "+formatDateToString(date, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "BDT"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `Calendar` or `Date`. Use either the java 8 time API or jodatime.

Comment: The server on which I am working doesnt have Java 8, we are currently on java 6 only so pls suggest accordingly

Comment: Hi Andy, do you have any example for a zone. I used it, it gave me time in ISO format which was not getting converted to UTC

Comment: You can get a `DateTimeZone` instance for a particular zone using `DateTimeZone.forID`. Note that you will likely need to use better timezone names than 3-letter ones, e.g. CST is ambiguous. You can get the current time using `new DateTime()`, and then convert that into a different time zone by calling `dateTimeInstance.withZone(dateTimeZoneInstance)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
        ZoneId zone2 = ZoneId.of("America/Santiago");
     LocalTime now2 = LocalTime.now(zone2);
    System.out.println(now2);
  }
}

Use the below link to know the timezones
```

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html

Comment: But the above code works in Java8 do anyone know the solution for java6

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.java.test;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.swing.text.ZoneView;

public class TestJavaCode {

/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try
{
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tzone = cal.getTimeZone();
tzone.useDaylightTime();
System.out.println("Timezone:"+tzone.getDisplayName());


TimeZone tzone1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Central");
TimeZoneIDProvide.getTimeZoneID(TimeZoneID.US_EASTERN).getTimeZone();

Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(tzone1); 
cal1.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis());

System.out.println("Time in US Hour: "+cal1.get(Calendar.HOUR));
System.out.println("Time in US Min: "+cal1.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
System.out.println("Time in US Sec: "+cal1.get(Calendar.SECOND));



}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("Exception caught:"+e);
}

}

}
```